# How many class schedules are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

You have $5$ choices of a math class, $2$ choices of history class, and $6$ choices of writing class. If you are planning to take one of each class, how many possible schedules could you have?

What I have so far is:
$5\times 2\times 6=60$

So I said that you could have $60$ different possible schedules.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfect.

Here you're asking first for the ways to choose one of the $5$ math classes.

For each of those, you choose one of the $2$ history classes, therefore, it's $5\times 2=10$ ways to choose one math class and one history class.

For each of those combinations you have to choose one of the $6$ writing class, therefore it's $5\times 2\times 6=60$ ways to choose one maths class, one history class and one writing class.